# Why does Android studio 2.3 produce bigger APK?

Tags: android-studio, size, apk

I just build a signed apk of my app and realise that the generated apk went from 15 to 23 MB.

It's a minor release with just minor bug fix and should not vary that much , so i launched the apk analyzer : 
[image]

if anything , my app should be smaller not 8Mb bigger...

On the other side , the claimed download size is close to the old apk's size.

**What can explain those extra 8MB ?**

Comment: Even me also getting same issues last update(android studio 2.2.3) it was 4MB now it is 24 MB i dnt know how it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS 2.3 automatically adjusts apk (zip) compression level to optimize app load time and update patches size. They also do not compress native libs now (to provide support for android:extractNativeLibs="false").

Comment: @Vitality where to write android:extractNativeLibs="false" ??

Comment: <application
   android:extractNativeLibs=”false”
   ...
>

Comment: @Vitality I added that tag with "true" and "false" also but release apk file size is not reduced... Its release apk size is 18mb and debug apk is 10mb...

Any suggestion?

Comment: The extractNativeLibs="false" will essentially prevent the system from creating a second copy of the .so files on-device at install time so your app will occupy less space on-device. Apk size will actually increase since with this option .so files will be stored uncompressed. If you want your so/apk be compressed, try to remove the extractNativeLibs flag from the manifest.

Comment: Note however that starting from Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2 and newest build tools, the build process will automatically store native libraries uncompressed in the apk (i.e. apk size will increase). The Play Store uses its own compression when sending apk files to users’ devices.